# An example for Spring Integration with spring-integration-jpa

Tags: spring-integration, channel, message-handlers

I see many examples related to spring-integration-file. But I am looking for an example application where it uses spring-integration-jpa to pull data from database using Inbound Channel Adapter and create a Java object out of it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Artem Bilan. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3):

There is a basic JPA sample in the official Spring Integration Samples repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jpa.

The simple Java DSL sample for Inbound Channel Adapter might look like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingAdapterFlow(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Jpa.inboundAdapter(entityManagerFactory)
                                .entityClass(StudentDomain.class)
                                .maxResults(1)
                                .expectSingleResult(true),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(new OnlyOnceTrigger())))
                .channel(c -> c.queue("pollingResults"))
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: Why are (almost) all the examples XML-based in that repository? It's so painfull.

Comment: Because they have been made those old days when only an XML configuration existed. Right now we just don't have enough resources to maintain Java DSL samples as well.

Comment: For java configurations you can see here https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jpa.html#configuring-with-java-configuration

Comment: FTR IntegrationFlows is now deprecated so this is no longer the correct answer.

Comment: Have just fixed my answer. Thanks